# Rails4.2 iPhoneのブラウザから更新すると画像が更新されてしまう

Tags: ruby-on-rails

herokuにアプリをアップしました。 
macbookのsafariからテストした時は問題なかったのですが、iPhoneからsafariとchromeテストした際に下記の問題が起きました。

Item modelでitemをcreateするとユーザが過去にcreateした全てのアイテムの画像(picture_1のみ)が更新されてしまいます。
新規でcreateしたitem自体はpicture_1とpicture_2が両方ともpicture_2の画像にに差し代わってしまいます。

原因が全くわかりません

**items/_form.html.erb**

```
<!--ファイルアップロードボタン -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="picture_1" class="col-sm-3 control-label">画像1&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <%= f.file_field :picture_1%>
    <%= f.hidden_field :picture_1_cache %>
    <% if item.picture_1? %>
        <figure class="thumbnail">
          <%= image_tag(item.picture_1_url(:thumb)) %>
        </figure>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
  <label for="picture_2" class="col-sm-3 control-label">画像2&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <%= f.file_field :picture_2%>
    <%= f.hidden_field :picture_2_cache %>
    <% if item.picture_2? %>
        <figure class="thumbnail">
          <%= image_tag(item.picture_2_url(:thumb)) %>
        </figure>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**item controller**

```
# 出品後の画面
def continue
end


def create
  @item = current_user.items.build(item_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @item.save
      format.html { redirect_to items_continue_url, notice: 'アイテムを登録しました' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @item }
    else

      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def update
  @update_item = current_user.items.find_by(id: params[:id], killer: false, limit_check: false)

  if @update_item.present?
    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.update(item_params)
        # 編集
        format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'アイテムを編集しました。' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @item }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: この情報だけでは推測が難しいと考えます。
iPhone から create したときのログを貼ると回答しやすくなると考えます。
またフォームの生成箇所の view と controller、 item のモデル
を追記されると良いと思います。